# Twitter Bootstrap panel height increases when resizing window

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having an issue where the height of one of my panels increases dramatically when I reduce the window size. Specifically, I have two panels in one row - one is col-grid-5 and the other is col-grid-4. The col-grid-4 header height (2nd one below AKA Recent Active Projects) is the one that is increasing way more than it should. Here's a plunkr:

http://plnkr.co/edit/NfI2xjth4ZU02duwLKDv

```
<div class="col-md-5">
        <div class="panel">
....
        </div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="panel">
....
        </div>
</div>
```

If you resize the window of the plunkr, you'll see it happen during a certain window width range. The problem goes away if I reorder the tables (i.e. put the 2nd one first). However, I can't figure out why that works.

Any tips would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a float clearing issue. You need to include another `.row` tag around your nested `.col-sm-6`'s. Simple answer is that any time you have a group of columns in bootstrap, you need a row around them.

```
    <div class="col-md-5">
        <div class="panel">
            <div class="panel-heading no-border bg-primary">
                <span class="text-lt">Time Summary</span>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="panel m-n col-sm-6 padder-v">
                Hours Today
                <i class="icon-arrow-right pull-right m-t-lg"></i>
                <div class="h2 b-b m-t-sm">2.50 </div>
              </div>
              ...
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Updated plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/rQqusAmUEWFrKMEqxRmz?p=preview

Comment: Thanks for your help - it solved the resizing issue. However, I just realized that I ran into an issue with the width of the nested columns. If you look closely at the borders, there's now an extra padding of 15px on the left and right of the nested columns. As a result, it doesn't line up with the panel header anymore. Any advice on how to solve that? I've been fiddling with the padding of the header to try to compensate but it hasn't helped.

Comment: @nairys rows add negative margins on the left and right, which causes the issue that you're seeing. Try replacing the inner `.row` with a `.clearfix` class instead, it will still fix your problem without changing the padding.